# Issue with opening and closing serial port

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port

I am currently working on C# application which requires to read serial port. In UI, there is a ON/OFF button which enables user click on it to start and stop reading data from serial port. If I continuously click on the button on and off. It threw an exception - Access to COM3 is denied or even said "The device is not connected". Can anyone suggest a better way to implement the serial port function which is able to resolve the situation as described above? Here is the code I use:

```
**// Start reading data from serial port**
public override void StartReading(string portname)
{
    try
    {
        int k = int.Parse(portname.Replace("COM", ""));
        if (startThread != null)
        {
            startThread.Abort();
            startThread = null;
        }

        startThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
        {
            isActive = true;
            try
            {
                using (SerialPort sp = new SerialPort(portname))
                {
                    if (!isActive)
                    {
                        DisposeBT(sp);
                        return;
                    }
                    sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);
                    if (!isActive)
                    {
                        DisposeBT(sp);
                        return;
                    }

                    if (!isActive)
                    {
                        DisposeBT(sp);
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(6500);
                        try
                        {
                            if (sp != null && !sp.IsOpen)
                            {
                                sp.Open();
                            }

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                           Logger.Warn("Failed to open the serial port for HRM once. Try it again.");
                            Logger.Error(ex);
                            ////////////////////// new added below
                            if(sp !=null && sp.IsOpen)
                            {
                                sp.Dispose();
                            }
                            Thread.Sleep(6500);
                            if (IsPortAvailable(k))
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    if (sp != null && !sp.IsOpen)
                                    {
                                        sp.Open();
                                    }

                                }
                                catch (Exception ex1)
                                {
                                    ////////////////////// new added below
                                    if (sp != null && sp.IsOpen)
                                    {
                                        sp.Dispose();
                                    }
                                    Logger.Warn("Failed to open the serial for HRM twice.");
                                    Logger.Error(ex1);
                                    // return;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    while (true)
                    {

                        if (!isActive)
                        {
                            DisposeBT(sp);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!isActive)
                    {
                        DisposeBT(sp);
                        return;
                    }
                    DisposeBT(sp);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Warn("Exception thrown for HRM.");
                Logger.Error(ex);
            }

        }));
        startThread.IsBackground = true;
        startThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
        startThread.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Warn("Failed to start reading for HRM02I3A1 bluetooth device.");
        Logger.Error(ex);
    }
}

// Stop reading data from serial port
public override void StopReading()
{
    try
    {
        isActive = false;
    }
    catch { }
}

// event handler for the serial port to read data from sp.
void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (isActive)// && startThread.IsAlive
    {
        SerialPort sp1 = (SerialPort)sender;
        try
        {
            sp1.Read(data, 0, 8);
            decoder.Decode(data);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Warn("------data received from Serial Port error for HRM-------");
            Logger.Error(ex);
        };
    }   
}
```

Comment: You cannot make this reliable, SerialPort needs additional time after Close() before it can be opened again.  Worst case is several seconds.  You'll need to make this a "logical" on/off, just throw stuff you receive away when it is off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first make background worker thread that accept the cancel event.

in the `DoWork` method you can write something like that

```
void DoWork{
    // init com port
    while(no body cancelled the background worker){
         // if there any waiting data receive and process it. do not use event handlers
    }
    // close the serial port so you can open it again later.
}
```

Also if you want to cancel the background work it would be a piece of cake

```
// send cancel command.
// wait till it is canceled.
```

Comment: Thanks, Mahmoud. Would you be able to provide some sample code on how to cancel or start the work?

Comment: for a good step by step tutorial check this out http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker

Comment: Is there any way to avoid "Access to COM21 is denied" when multiple click on the ON/OFF Button occurs? Since I started to use background thread worker, it still have the same exception being thrown.

Comment: if it is opened and you forgot to close it from the last time it would cause access is denied I have edited my answer please check it to find where to close the serial port.

Comment: Do i need to do this when the user click STOP? 'code' startThread.DoWork -= startThread_DoWork;
                    startThread.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
                    startThread.RunWorkerCompleted -= startThread_RunWorkerCompleted;
                    startThread.CancelAsync();
                    startThread.Dispose(); 'code'

Comment: do not play with even wiring at all. just stop/start the BGW it should not require that much effort to do event wiring yourself.

Comment: Mahmoud, Is there any way which can improve the performance over a long time when multiple backgroundworkers are running? The UI doesn't freeze, but I have a feeling that it is going to freeze.

Comment: you are dealing with serial port(s) which means you should not expect too much of performance. however the BGWs will not freeze the App do not worry about that.

Comment: Hi, Is there anyone know why the dowork doesn't fire anymore after the background worker has been cancelled by calling cancelasyn() function after few minutes?

Comment: CancelAsync does not mean the Worker will stop it means it has sent cancel request so the worker should be watching this flag to exit. failing to do so can cause the issue you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `startThread.Join()` directly after the call to `startThread.Abort()`.

Take a look at the [msdn documentation on Thread.Abort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b50fdsz.aspx) and perhaps you also should check what [join does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx).